# Xmanager not working on Centos

Tags: linux, ssh, centos6, x11-forwarding

I am trying to take a gui session of a centos machine on my linux machine. I am receiving the following error:

[image: Xrcmd error message]

Comment: The sshd server isn't allowing it. You have to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config to allow X11 Forwarding.

Comment: its enabled. but i checked out the log xterm is not installed. How to do that ?

Comment: If xterm is not installed it means there is no X11 installed. Without X11, sshd can't forward any X11. You need to install X11/xorg packages. You can yum list *X11* or *xorg* to list all X11/xorg packages. At minimum you will need xorg-X11-server.

Comment: i have installed xterm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type the following command :

```
yum install xorg-x11-xauth xterm
```

It will work.